# Calling array within array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array called `my-array` like so:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

If I access the array like this: `array('my-array')`

What is the code to get to `my-array -> c -> z`

Thanks

Comment: Read the manual. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

**1st Not my-array its my_array**
A sample,

```
$shop = array( array("rose", 1.25 , 15),
               array("daisy", 0.75 , 25),
               array("orchid", 1.15 , 7) 
             );
```

> $shop[0] is  array("rose", 1.25 , 15) 
>    So  $shop[0][0] is
>   "rose"

on yours `my_array['c'][2]`   will help

Answer (score -1):

The format would be as follows:

```
echo $myArray['c'][2];
```

The `->` is reserved for objects, not arrays.

For arrays with named elements (assosiative arrays) you use the name in quotes, for indexed arrays (numeric values for elements) you use no quotes.

Comment: that should `echo $myArray['c'][2];`

Comment: @ThomasK Right you are! Corrected.

Answer (score -1):

`z` is not a valid key in the array. It would be

```
$array['c'][2];
```

To get the value `z` of the key `2`.

Answer (score -1):

You can access array like this:

```
$myArray['c'][0];
```

You can't **access** array with `array('my-array')` in PHP. It's the way to declare it.

For example:

```
$someArr = array('a' => 'some', 'b' => 'thing', 'c' => array('another', 'array'));
```

Moreover `z` is not a key here. It's a value of `$myArray['c'][2]`.